# Wrong data received in javaScript using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, call

I made multi calls AJAX in my file.js, the calls have the next form:

> file.js

```
$.post('functions.php',{consulta: 'tbl_Cours', action: {"ask_query_field":variable1}).val()}, function(res1){ 
  if (res1){
    //do something
  } 

  //Second call
  $.post('functions.php',{consulta: 'tbl_Cours', action: {"ask_query_field":variable2}}, function(res2){ 
    if(res2){
      //do something
    } 

    //third call
    $.post('functions.php',{consulta: 'tbl_Cours', action: {"ask_query_field":variable3}}, function(res3){ 
      if(res3){
        console.log(res3);
      } 
    });
  });
});
```

So, first and second calls return All very well, I call the same file *functions.php* and the same function. But in the third call I get a data but it's different that data sent from  the server server php.

I saw the log in php and show that return this:

> log from php

```
[30-Jan-2018 11:06:50 America/Chicago] Array
(
  [tema] => Tema 1 .- Introducción y definiciones
  [pk_tema] => 3
  [cantidad] => 1
)

[30-Jan-2018 11:06:50 America/Chicago] Array
(
  [tema] => Tema 2 .- Posiciones y valoraciones
  [pk_tema] => 4
  [cantidad] => 3
)

[30-Jan-2018 11:06:50 America/Chicago] Array
(
  [tema] => Tema 3 .- Practicas y actividades
  [pk_tema] => 5
  [cantidad] => 3
)
```

Next, in the Javascript I see what I've received and the data is different

```
>>  {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}}
0:{tema: "Tema 1 .- Introducción y definiciones", pk_tema: "3", cantidad: "1"}
1:{tema: "Tema 2 .- Posiciones y valoraciones", pk_tema: "4", cantidad: "4"}
2:{tema: "Tema 3 .- Practicas y actividades", pk_tema: "5", cantidad: "3"}
```

The pk_tema:4 now have the *cantidad* :4 before in functions.js had 3. 
I've tried

1. change the name of variable to result Ex: res3 to *data_received*, the result is the same.
2. Put $.ajaxSetup({async: false}); because I thought that it was problem of synchronicy. But the result is the same.
3. I executed the third call by the console and the result is fine.

So, I don't sure What is my prblem I use php7 and jQuery v1.12.4. in Google Chrome

Comment: It looks good to me. The object in php log is the same as the object in javascript. In JS it looks like an object with 3 objects inside it, but all the data is there.

Comment: Look at developer tools / Network / find your third ajax call / look at response tab. There you will see raw data recieved. Check if these data are correct.

Comment: @Karl thanks for see my ask but if you see, the information change in php _pk_tema:4_ and _cantidad:3_ and in JavaScript is _pk_tema:4_ and _cantidad:4_ .

Comment: @bigless The data received it's ok. so the problem pass after, I'm not sure what happend with this variable.because I don't use in the future. But You are Right, the problem pass after and it don't afected me.

Comment: @alfonsovelasco3622 what is the ".val()" in the first request for?

It would be cool if you could use an async.waterfall() for this.

Comment: @Karl it was a finger error, Sorry It's my first ask, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bigless , because I didn't check the all tools of developers, I received the data corrrect in JavaScript but I'm not sure why it change with the time, I will never use twice the variable *res3* but the information that it has change. Thanks so much for you time.

```
0:{tema: "Tema 1 .- Introducción y definiciones", pk_tema: "3", cantidad: "1"}
1:{tema: "Tema 2 .- Posiciones y valoraciones", pk_tema: "4", cantidad: "3"}
2:{tema: "Tema 3 .- Practicas y actividades", pk_tema: "5", cantidad: "3"}
```

Comment: Objects are mutable. You may be mutating it between logging it and expending it in the developer tools. The console will show the value of the object at the moment you expand it in the dev tools, not at the moment it was logged.

Comment: @FelixKling so if I understand your advice, basically `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res3)))` should print recieved value

Comment: Yes you are right @FelixKling , the value is different when I use the console. and I didn't undertand what append, but now I know, thanks for you answer, now how can I put this Ask in status to 
resolved?